# http GET request not working with localhost

Tags: java, rest, get, request

I'm using below code to forward a GET request :

```
public String getHTML(String urlToRead) {
          URL url;
          HttpURLConnection conn;
          BufferedReader rd;
          String line;
          String result = "";
          try {
             url = new URL(urlToRead);
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
             rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
             while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
             }
             rd.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return result;
       }
```

But this line :

```
getHTML("http://localhost:8080/myapp/serv/create");
```

causes this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
```

I think this is because I am using the word localhost ? So the URL cannot be parsed correctly ? I require this code to work on multiple different machines so cannot use my IP as each machine will have unique IP. Is there an another alternative for this to work

Comment: For which line are you getting this exception?

Comment: Works fine for me. Perhaps you don't have a `doGET` on `/myapp/serv/create` in your server.

Comment: @barak manos Eclipse was not compiling the current code. I don;t know why. clean & build fixed the issue. How I discovered this : when I attempted to set a breakpoint the variables in debug view did not match variables defined in method/class. Thanks for your comment

Comment: You're welcome :) ... Eclipse does appear to have this tendency sometimes...